# How to solve the below error? I am making a project which is a golf game

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, fabricjs

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at Function.t.fabric.Image.fabric.Image.fromURL.

This is the error tried nearly everthing and didn't work

Comment: might be infinite loop

Comment: Not infinite loop but recursion.